# dataSource injection in SpringFramework2 throws exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, datasource, integration-testing

I use the Spring Framework 2.5.6
I have the following dataSource defined in my spring-beans.xml file which I use in order to connect in my remote database :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>

</bean>
```

This is how my jUnit integration test looks like :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "spring-beans.xml")
public class MyIntegrationTest {

   @Autowired
   DataSource dataSource;

}
```

I have copied the spring-beans.xml file in the same package where the test case code which I have uploaded resides.

However I get the following exception when I run the test case :

```
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@9a8d9b] to prepare test instance [tests.GuestBookDirectComm@22c6bb6c] 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:201)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:255)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:111)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:148)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:61)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:54)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:52)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [tests/spring-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [tests/spring-beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:42)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:173)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:197)
    ... 17 more


Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [tests/spring-beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    ... 26 more
```

Any ideas why this could be happening ?

Comment: It is looking for the xml file in a directory called test and not finding it. The test directory must be somewhere other than where you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `spring-beans.xml` into the classpath--not the package where your source code is.

If you are using Maven or Gradle to build, then put the file in *src/test/resources*.

Otherwise, put it wherever and manually load it with [FileSystemXmlApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html) in the setup for your test fixture.

Comment: I wrote this code in the setUpBeforeClass : ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/src/main/resources/spring-beans.xml"); However how can I use the context variable to load the data in the @Autowired DataSource dataSource ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven you should use the src/test/resources folder. Maven can copy it over while running the tests.

Comment: I am using maven that's right . But the tests are not in the src/test/java folder but in another folder insinde the src/main/java . I use the src/main/resources folder but it still does not find it